# How to loop through subnets in a resource using count

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In Terraform 0.11.14 , the following was possible to loop through the different subnets retrieved earlier in a data variable (cf. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet_ids.html ):

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "private" {
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"

  tags = {
    Tier = "Private"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "app" {
  count         = "3"
  ami           = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = "${element(data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids, count.index)}"
}
```

However, since I migrated to Terreform 0.12, this syntax results in the following error:

```
Error: Error in function call

  on ..\..\modules\elk\es-proxy-server.tf line 21, in resource "aws_spot_instance_request" "kibana_proxy":
  21:   subnet_id = "${element(data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids, count.index)}"
    |----------------
    | count.index is 0
    | data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids is set of string with 2 elements

Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from set of string.
```

I tried to use the tolist function and to work out how to take benefit of the following https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html#working-with-count-on-resources without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
subnet_id     = "${tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids)[count.index]}"
```